# Help me find the point of intersection of a line and a point.

Tags: calculus, circles

Find the equation of the circle with its center at $(-1,-3)$ and tangent to the line through the point $(-2,4)$ and $(2,1)$.

The line is $3x+4y=10$ and the point is $(-1,-3)$. What's the better formula in getting the point of intersection and the distance? Thank you! ;)

My answer is $(x+1)^2 + (y+3)^2 = 25$

Comment: "_Verify my answer_" ... can you please add your answer? What are you unsure about with it?

Comment: That point is not on that line, so what do you mean by "the point of intersection"?

Comment: I'm sorry. Please read again my question. I have edited it already.

Comment: Your answer is correct. You can verify it by using Desmos online graphing calculator. This is the link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ygousigril

Comment: By "the better formula" do you mean you want a single, complete formula giving the point on a given line closest to a given point and another for the distance from a point to a line, or do you mean simple methods with multiple steps that will give you the answers? [Here are the formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Cartesian_coordinates).

Comment: Thank you guys! I just want this homework to be sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is absolutely correct. To answer your question, you already know the equation is $(x +1)^{2} + (y + 3)^{2} = r^2$, where r is the radius. This radius is nothing but the distance of the center $(-1, -3)$ from the line $3x + 4y = 10$. You probably know the formula for distance of a point from a line. Rory Daulton has already provided you with the formulae.  So that's it. Hope this helps

Comment: @Lulu, No problem providing with some help when most of the effort is visible.

Answer (score 0):

For a vector approach to this problem let $u=B-A, v=C-A$.  Then the vector projection of $v$ onto $u$ gives a vector from $A$ to the point of tangency $P$ with $P=A+\frac{u.v}{v.v} v$

Comment: Hi John, thanks. I guess that vector approach is difficult for me. I'll just use your previous suggestion of getting the distance. :)